# remove white color of image javascript causes return of nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I used the following code to remove white color in image. It works for the image of the original fiddle, but it doesn't work with mine. I believe the code is totally fine, and it's a problem with the image I use, but why? And how can I make it work for my image?

Working with original image in tutorial: https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/UuCys/3/

NOT working with my image (I simply replace the img src): http://jsfiddle.net/UuCys/119/

Here is the code

When I try to return each pixel before changes, every pixel has 0 value for red,green or blue...why?

```
function white2transparent(img)
{
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');

    var w = img.width, h = img.height;

    c.width = w;
    c.height = h;

    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0, w, h);
    var pixel = imageData.data;

    var r=0, g=1, b=2,a=3;
    for (var p = 0; p<pixel.length; p+=4)
    {
      if (
          pixel[p+r] == 255 &&
          pixel[p+g] == 255 &&
          pixel[p+b] == 255) // if white then change alpha to 0
      {pixel[p+a] = 0;}
    }

    ctx.putImageData(imageData,0,0);

    return c.toDataURL('image/png');
}
```

Comment: Possible same-origin issue: "`Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.`"

Comment: Oh thank you! I googled what this means and it seems like it's a security settings of the other domain , not allowing me to change their images.